# Error using "condition paramter header" @StreamListener of new release Chelsea.RC1

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am trying to use the event filter to reduce the amount of topics the application uses using the new feature available in the new release of the spring cloud stream (Chelsea.RC1). The message is being created, with the correct header, however, inspecting the contents of the message in the queue, the message does not contain the header, only the body with the payload.

```
public void sendEnroll(EnrollCommand data) {

    //MessageChannel
    outputEnroll.send(MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(data)
                .setHeader("brand", "MASTERCARD")
                .setHeader("operation", Operation.ENROLL).build());
}
```

Consumer

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(Channel.class)
public class EnrollConsumer {

@Autowired
private EnrollService service;

@StreamListener(target = Channel.INPUT_ENROLL, condition = "headers['brand']=='MASTERCARD'")
public void enrollConsumer(@Payload String command){
    System.out.println(command);
    //service.enrollment(command);
 }
}
```

In consumer service, it gives the following warning:

```
WARN -kafka-listener-1 o.s.c.s.b.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler:62 - Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for message with id: 7baae934-7484-a7fd-91b0-ba906558bb13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to map that your custom headers:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers = brand,operation
```

That information is present in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_configuration_options_2).